# Docker container works on Ubuntu but fails to run on MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, docker

Sorry if this is a stupid and/or widely known question.

I've written a docker that basically just runs a single process then exits. It runs fine on my ubuntu machine 16.04 and its been tested on another ubuntu machine. However, someone else has tested out the docker on macos and the docker did not run to completion.

Is this a known limitation of docker? i.e. can linux dockers only run on linux, macos dockers only run on macos, etc... Or is it even more restrictive in that is only works on the same OS (i.e. ubuntu dockers should only be run on ubuntu).

The docker itself is an image processing pipeline. We run it by mounting a directory that contains the image and then mount an output directory as well and just run a process inside the container. I'll post more details of the docker if that's important to the answer.

Comment: Docker on MacOS *is* running under Linux (in a VM).  For us to help with this question, you would need to provide more technical details: What are you trying to mount? Why is the container failing? Are there any errors? Can you provide a minimal Dockerfile that would reproduce the problem if we were to run it on MacOS?

Comment: Are these two different versions of Docker?

Comment: If they are mounting files from MacOS then they need to make sure it is from specific paths like `/Users`, `/tmp`, `/private`, `/Volumes`. See this article for more details https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces

Comment: @larsks if it's running inside a vm, is it possible the docker container on macos is running out of memory or something? This is a very memory intensive process...

Answer (score 0):

Since docker runs as a vm on macos, you have to specify the memory. The docker uses 8 gigs of ram and was running out of memory. The solution was to boost the vm memory to 8 gigs and it worked fine...